# Proper way to populate dropdown from foreign key in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

can anyone help me in solving this problem? I've been stuck for days with the error **htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given** in Laravel 5.3.

Here is my controller

```
public function create()
    {
      $categories = DB::table('categories')->pluck('name', 'id');
      foreach($categories as $category)
      {
          echo $category;
      }
      return view('admin.processor.create', compact('categories', $categories));
    }
```

And here's my view (the form)

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/processor']) !!}
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('make', 'Manufacturer') !!}
        {!! Form::select('make', ['Intel', 'AMD', 'Apple', 'Qualcomm', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('chipset', 'Chipset') !!}
        {!! Form::text('chipset', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('type', 'Type') !!}
        {!! Form::text('type', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('category', 'Category') !!}
        {!! Form::select('categories', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Add Processor', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I just want to achieve something equivalent to this

```
<select class="form-control" name="category">
    <?php 
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
      print "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

My Category Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function processor()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Processor', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

My Processor Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Processor extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['make', 'chipset', 'type', 'category_id'];

    public function category()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Controller

```
$categories = DB::table('categories')->pluck('name', 'id');
return view('admin.processor.create', compact('categories'));
```

View

```
{!! Form::select('categories', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: I've tried but it says "BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2450:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()"

Comment: you don't need to pass `$categories` as a second argument inside the` compact()` function.

Comment: Now I'm back to "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" error again. I wonder what is wrong...

Comment: @AdiKurniawan try this: `DB::table('categories')->pluck('name', 'id')->toJson();` hope this work now

Comment: Still getting the same error. I'll edit my question and add my Models. Hopefully it will give you some hints

Comment: @AdiKurniawan i got you problem just replace his code:
        `{!! Form::text('chipset', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}    
   
        {!! Form::text('type', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}` define `null` after your text field name.

Comment: Still won't do and now it returns a new error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". I read somewhere that the Laravel Collective and Laravel's Query Builder are bugged. That's why they removed it in Laravel 5.3. And that's what I'm gonna do, reverting back to normal html form instead of using the Form helper. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @AdiKurniawan Try this: `DB::table('categories')->pluck('name', 'id')` it will works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

So for those who are facing the same problem and still getting the **htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given** in Laravel 5.3, I'd suggest that you use the normal html form instead of the Form helper from Laravel Collective.

Here's what I did
My Controller

```
public function create()
    {
      $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id');
      return view('admin.processor.create', ['categories' => $categories]);
    }
```

And the view

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('category') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control" required autofocus>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{ $category }}">{{ $category }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

You should be able to display the create page now. Hopefully it helps.